# NodeJS async/await and forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach, async-await

I am using NodeJS version v10.15.3 and I have a code something like this:

```
async getItems(): Promise<Array<any>> {
    let retArray = [];
    await some.list.forEach(async function (someObj) {
        let item = new Item();
        await item.initialize(someObj);
        await retArray.push(item);
    }
    console.log("retArray="+JSON.stringify(retArray));
    retrn retArray;
}


async mainFunction() {
    let items = await getItems()
    console.log("items="+JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

When I call the `mainFunction()`, and when I log its result(the `items`), it does contain the expected value.  But the weird thing is that inside this `getItems()` function, even with `await` on `forEach` (which adds an item to the `retArray`), when I print the `retArray` after the `forEach` right before the function returns it, it doesn't have the full value in it.  I `await` for item to `initialize`, and I even await for the item to be `push`ed to the `retArray`.

It just doesn't make sense that this log shows empty list

> console.log("retArray="+JSON.stringify(retArray));

yet this log shows full list that I expect.

> console.log("items="+JSON.stringify(items));

How can I make it so that after the `forEach`, when I reference `retArray` like below

> console.log("retArray="+JSON.stringify(retArray));

the `retArray` actually does contain the full data it gathered?

Comment: You could use a for()-loop instead of the foreach

Comment: or use `.map` and then `await Promise.all` on the resulting array of Promises.